# Grab a field without a fixed position via awk

Tags: bash, awk

I'm working on a script to wake different LCs on my LAN. MAC-Adresses are hard to memorize so I made myself a list that contains information about the respective PCs. Right now the list looks like:

```
dragoner xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
theseus yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy
...
```

That means, that new entries will always have to be in the form: `netbios-name ipv4 mac`. The advantage is, that such a list can easily be queried by `grep` and `awk`.

I'd rather like to have a list like that:

```
netbios=dragoner ip4=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx mac=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
netbios=theseus mac=yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy ip4=yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
...
```

In that manner new information could be added more easily and row wouldn't have to have a certain number of columns... but I'm failing to query it via awk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In either list format you should be able to just search it. I'm not sure what you're trying to *do* past simple lookups but thanks to their relative formats, MAC addresses are always going to contain `:`, IPs `.` and netbios should be clean of both.

What doesn't `grep '1.2.3.4' mylist` do?

And you could be really bashy about this and do something like:

```
source <(grep '1.2.3.4' mylist)
echo "$netbios $ip"
```

Comment: That does the trick quite elegant.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{
    delete fields
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        split($i, f, /=/)
        fields[f[1]] = f[2]
    }
    # do something with fields["ipv4"], fields["mac"], fields["netbios"]
}' filename
```

Or, don't use awk, use bash

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    eval "declare $line"
    # do something with $ipv4, $mac, $netbios
done < filename
```